# Why does "keyof" not work on this generic type inside a Proxy() returned by a class constructor?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble using a generic type in combination with `keyof` inside a `Proxy()`:

The below sample code doesn't work, and complains about not having any assignable types:

```
interface SomeDataStructure {
    name?:string;
}

class DataWrapper<T extends SomeDataStructure> {
    data:T;
    
    constructor( data:T ) {
        this.data = data;

        return new Proxy( this, {
            get: ( target:this, property:keyof T ) : any => {
                return target.data[ property ];
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

The error (on `get`):

```
Type '(target: this, property: keyof T) => any' is not assignable to type '(target: this, p: 
string | symbol, receiver: any) => any'.
  Types of parameters 'property' and 'p' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"name"'.ts(2322)
```

If I use `keyof SomeDataStructure` directly, instead of `keyof T`, the error disappears and everything seems fine:

```
interface SomeDataStructure {
    name?:string;
}

class DataWrapper<T extends SomeDataStructure> {
    data:T;
    
    constructor( data:T ) {
        this.data = data;

        return new Proxy( this, {
            get: ( target:this, property:keyof SomeDataStructure ) : any => {
                return target.data[ property ];
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, writing `keyof T extends SomeDataStructure` (like in the class definition) works as well. Using `keyof T` in general for class methods outside of the `Proxy()` works fine as well.

I have to assume that the type of `T` is somehow lost when wrapping things in `new Proxy()`. How can I re-use `T` for `keyof T` here?

Comment: There's a weirdness here that TypeScript's type for `DataWrapper<T>` does not extend `T` (indeed you can't write such a thing with a `class` declaration).  So TS will not accept `new DataWrapper({name: "abc"}).name` and it *will* accept `new DataWrapper({name:"abc"}).data.name` which explodes at runtime. You're not asking about this, so it's kind of a distraction that someone running this code would hit these problems.  Could you [edit] the question to fix this issue, maybe by just making the `Proxy` without *returning* it in the constructor?

Comment: @jcalz well, the `return new Proxy` is kind of the whole point of this class. My whole goal here, down the line, is to have an object wrapped in a way where I can extend the `set` method to set a flag if any data was changed, without forcing me to use `setValue()` type of methods. I mean, I can easily write this behavior in plain JS, so there has to be some way to get it to work in TS? Even if its just a series of guards.

Comment: It might be the point of the class but it's not the question you're asking, and is out of scope for this question.  I was just letting you know it doesn't do what you think it should do.  If you want to ask "how can I write a strongly-typed `DateWrapper<T>` proxy class in TS" you should probably post a new question for it (after searching for existing questions that might answer that).  I'm happy to discuss it and think about it, but not here where the question is about `keyof T`.  For *this* question you should probably remove the `return new Proxy` thing, since it's, at best, distracting.

Comment: FWIW [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wj8nlm) might be the kind of thing you're looking for; essentially TS can't model this sort of thing with class declarations so the best you can do is to write a nearly-untyped class and then assert that it behaves as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe to assume that `property` is of type `keyof T`, but TypeScript normally allows get handlers to make unsafe assumptions about `property`. The reason you get an error is because `keyof T` is unsafe in a way that confuses the compiler.

---

First: it's not safe to assume `property` is of type `keyof T`.

Your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` is merely [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `SomeDataStructure`, meaning that it could be a *subtype* of `SomeDataStructure` with more properties than `SomeDataStructure` knows about:

```
const dw = new DataWrapper({
  name: "abc",
  otherProp: 123,
  4: true,
}); // compiles okay
```

Furthermore, the actual `data` passed in could be of a *subtype of `T`* with properties not even known about in `T`:

```
interface Foo extends SomeDataStructure {
  name: string
  otherProp: number,
  4: boolean
}
const bar = { name: "abc", otherProp: 123, 4: true, yetAnotherProp: "hello" };
const foo: Foo = bar; // okay
const dw2 = new DataWrapper(foo);
// const dw2: DataWrapper<Foo>
```

Here `dw2` is of type `DataWrapper<Foo>` yet the actual data has a `yetAnotherProp` property not known about in `Foo`.  This is just the way [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) works in TypeScript, and it's intentional.

---

So technically your proxy handler should be prepared to receive *any property key whatsoever*, not just `keyof T`.  And [the TypeScript `ProxyHandler` typings for `get`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a404f3d7805ff90b5c1eea82580ea914b52da610/src/lib/es2015.proxy.d.ts#L36) say that the `property` parameter should be of type `string | symbol` accordingly.

But since it is declared with *method syntax* (`{ get(⋯): ⋯ }`) instead of *function property syntax* (`{ get: (⋯) => ⋯ }`), TypeScript treats it as being [*bivariant* in its parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), meaning it will accept both the safe version where you annotate `property` to be *wider* than `string | symbol`, but also the *unsafe but convenient* version where you annotate `property` to be *narrower* than `string | symbol`.

That means if you change `keyof T` to `"bloop"` the error goes away because even though assuming `property` will be `"bloop"` is unsafe, it's narrower than `string | symbol` and hence allowed:

```
new Proxy(this, {
  get: (target: this, property: "bloop"): any => { // okay!
    return "";
  }
});
```

Unfortunately for you, `keyof T` is *neither* wider nor narrower than `string | symbol`.  The type `keyof T` is allowed to contain `number` elements, like `4` shown above.  Of course in reality, such keys are coerced to `string`s, and that key will really be `"4"`.  But there are places where TypeScript pretends that keys can be `number`s, mostly to allow indexing into [arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) with numbers, and hence the existence of a "numeric" [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

And `property` can't be `number` due to a change in [microsoft/TypeScript#35594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35594) to fix a bug reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#39272](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39272) that `number` will never be passed to the handler.  So they changed it from `string | number | symbol` (`keyof T` is narrower than that) to `string | symbol` (`keyof T` is not narrower than that).

So you get an error. `keyof T` is unsafe, but not in a way the compiler allows.

---

What can you do to fix it?  The "right" thing is to write code that can deal with any `string | symbol` property whatsoever. If you're not concerned about the possibility of extra keys, then you might want to just [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) `number` from `keyof T` so that it's seen as narrower and the bivariance kicks in:

```
interface SomeDataStructure {
  name?: string;
}

class DataWrapper<T extends SomeDataStructure> {
  data: T;

  constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data;

    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: (target: this, property: Exclude<keyof T, number>): any => { // okay
        return target.data[property];
      }
    });
  }
}
```

That works now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-Q91oG08AqzS91HHXSk3UHUY5soiAA)

Comment: The first thing I tried at the start, was accepting "everything", and just filtering inside the function with guards - but Typescript didn't like that either (it kind of just ignored my `if`s for some reason). Its interesting how far you had to dig for that 'number' detail, but your Exclude suggestion seems to do the trick. This is sadly just step 1 for me, so I might have to open another question soon (as the end goal is a union type, which also seems to confuse TS)... but at least it solves this part. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, as I was researching this I kept saying "wow, really?" at each part, since it's a strange interaction of about three or four different TypeScript behaviors.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for figuring it out and the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting is correct: TypeScript refuses to believe that a `string | symbol` is assignable to `keyof T`. And this is reasonable enough, they are two different types. ("Assignable" means that `string | symbol` must be equal to or more narrow than `keyof T` - which is obviously untrue.)

The problem of not being able to tell TypeScript that, in fact, it should always expect `keyof T` to be passed there, is caused by the fact that `ProxyHandler` is, IMHO, badly typed. You can observe that by clicking on the `get` function in your editor and going to its type definition.

Currently the typing is: `get?(target: T, p: string | symbol, receiver: any): any;`

While what you want is: `get?<K = keyof T>(target: T, p: K, receiver: any): T[K];`

With the second typing, you would be able to communicate with TS way more precisely:

```
get: <K extends keyof T>(target: this, property: K): T[K] => {
  const value = target.data[ property ];
  return value; // correctly evaluates to `T[K]`
}
```

You can test this in your editor if you simply edit your `lib.es20XX.proxy.d.ts` file and add the alternative typing there:

```
    /**
     * A trap for getting a property value.
     * @param target The original object which is being proxied.
     * @param p The name or `Symbol` of the property to get.
     * @param receiver The proxy or an object that inherits from the proxy.
     */
    get?(target: T, p: string | symbol, receiver: any): any;
    get?<K = keyof T>(target: T, p: K, receiver: any): T[K];
```

I'm sorry to say that my knowledge here doesn't go further than that. I'm not sure if there is a simple inline solution that would let you narrow the native typing without adding your own `.d.ts` files. Maybe someone else will be able to chime in and give you more actionable advice.